# Fuel pump on a Subaru Outback

Tags: subaru, fuel-pump, outback

Hello can anyone tell me where the fuel pump is located in a Subaru Outback 2003 model? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is in the gas tank. It can be accessed from under the back seat.

Comment: More info & procedures can be found in the factory service manual @ https://jdmfsm.info/Auto/Japan/Subaru/Legacy_Outback/